# margin subtitle html player

Tags: html, css

I can do something with ::cue to custom subtitle

```
.media-player ::cue {
  color: $subtitle-color;
  font-size: $subtitle-size;
  background: $subtitle-background;
}
```

But I can't use margin-bottom to push up subtitle. Any idea to do this

Comment: we cant predict where your error is..So try to make a fiddle doc in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: you can see picture [here](https://github.com/thelordofthetimes/web.media/issues/1)

and code [here](https://github.com/thelordofthetimes/web.media/blob/master/src/sass/subtitle.scss)

I hope help me, please

Comment: make a fiddle your code is all over the place

Comment: I have to agree, make a jsfiddle so we can see what you have and better help you.

Comment: thank all for comments, [this is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqm2amue/19). In case, subtitle is not config to crossorigin, so it's can not display. if display, it's have red color. I want margin-bottom subtitle, but I can't. Can you help me ?